# Stripe Token not passed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to:

- Create Customer
- Create Purchase

To do this, I am  using this javascript code in my `purchases.js` (for my purchases controller):

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  jQuery.externalScript = function(url, options) {
    options = $.extend(options || {}, {
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true,
      url: url
    });
    return jQuery.ajax(options);
  };

  $.externalScript('https://js.stripe.com/v1/').done(function(script, textStatus) {
     Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
     var purchase = {
       setupForm: function() {
         return $('.card_form').submit(function() {
           $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
           if ($('#card_number').length) {
             purchase.processCard();
             return false;
           } else {
             return true;
           }
         });
       },
       processCard: function() {
         var card;
         card = {
         name: $('#name_on_card').val(),
         number: $('#card_number').val(),
         cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
         expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
         expYear: $('#card_year').val()
       };
       return Stripe.createToken(card, purchase.handleStripeResponse);
     },
     handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
       if (status === 200) {
         $('#purchase_stripe_token').val(response.id)
         $('.card_form')[0].submit()
       } else {
         $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();
         return $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
       }
     }
   };
   return purchase.setupForm();
 });
});
```

This works fine.

My issue is, I am trying to create a recipient. To do this, I basically use the same code, swapping out the respective fields for the recipient creation. BUT before I do this, I attempt to submit the form (essentially creating a purchase from a different controller), but in the second controller, it does not pass the stripe_token.

What would be the cause for this -- the code is basically the same? I'm not versed in JS.

**UPDATE**
THIS IS THE JAVASCRIPT THAT DOES NOT WORK.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  jQuery.externalScript = function(url, options) {
    options = $.extend(options || {}, {
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true,
      url: url
    });
    return jQuery.ajax(options);
  };

  $.externalScript('https://js.stripe.com/v1/').done(function(script, textStatus) {
      Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
      var bank = {
        setupForm: function() {
          return $('.recipient_form').submit(function() {
            $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
            if ($('#account_number').length) {
              bank.processBankAccount();
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          });
        },
        processBankAccount: function() {
          var details;
          details = {
            country: $('#country').val(),
            routingNumber: $('#routing_number').val(),
            accountNumber: $('#account_number').val()
          };
          return Stripe.createToken(details, bank.handleStripeResponse);
        },
        handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
          if (status === 200) {
            $('#bank_stripe_token').val(response.id)
            $('.recipient_form')[0].submit()
          } else {
            $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();
            return $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        }
      };
      return bank.setupForm();
    });
 });
```

THIS IS THE FORM.

```
<%= form_for([@user, @bank], role: "form", html:{class: "recipient_form"}) do |f| %>


<%= label_tag :country, "Country"%>
<%= text_field_tag :country, nil, name: nil, required: true %>

<%= label_tag :routing_number, "Routing Number"%>
<%= text_field_tag :routing_number, nil, name: nil, required: true %>

<%= label_tag :account_number, "Accounting Number"%>
<%= text_field_tag :account_number, nil, name: nil, required: true %>

<%= f.hidden_field :stripe_token %>

<%= f.submit value: "ADD" %>
<% end %>
```

THE CONTROLLER.

```
class BanksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @bank = @user.build_bank
  end

 def create
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @bank = @user.build_bank

   stripe_token = params[:bank][:stripe_token]

   begin
     if !stripe_token.present?
       raise "Stripe token not present. Cannot process transaction."
     end
     recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
       :name => "Person Name",
       :type => "individual",
       :bank_account => stripe_token )
    end
  end
end
```

FORM DATA:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "bank"=>{"stripe_token"=>""},
  "commit"=>"ADD",
  "user_id"=>"1680"}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the Stripe SDK? You probably shouldn't be performing anything except the token generation on the client side. Unless you're building this in Node...

Comment: unfamiliar with stripe sdk

Comment: Have a look https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer makes the process A LOT easier. You only need to worry about generating the token, and their SDK takes care of the rest.

Comment: Oh, that's basically what I use. I'm having trouble generating the token with the js. I do the rest through the controller. The error I get (only when creating a recipient) is that the stripe token is not being generated.

Comment: Are you including the card details when creating it? You can't create a customer without attaching a card. Customers by themselves don't have a token, only cards do

Comment: Yes -- I have a `purchases` controller and a `recipients` controller. I use the code above for a purchase, and it works fine. I then attempt to use basically the same code the create a recipient (bank_account is the token, and it includes accountNumber, routingNumber, bankName, and country), but it does not save this info as a token. It passes an empty string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the form data being passed? `console.log(card);`

Comment: Ok, give me like 15 min. Need to re-create it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: added, i'm also adding the controller and actual js

Comment: Sorry, I meant I need to see an actual sample of the form data you're throwing at the form.

Comment: added form data (server parameters) -- i think that's what you want?

Comment: na, the part before you get to the stripe token - it's not being generated, and it's probably something to do with the card data not being set properly. So around the point where you're creating the customer based on the form input fields.

Comment: in the code i posted (the second part), i'm trying to create a recipient. no card or customer. i can create a customer, card, and purchase fine... i'm having trouble when trying to use similar code to create a recipient. a recipient can receive transfer from my stripe account to a third party bank account

Comment: Yeah I get that. This part: `return Stripe.createToken(details, bank.handleStripeResponse);` I need to know the contents of `details` in order to debug further, because that's what's being passed to the stripe token generator. Redact what you need to, that's fine - but without knowing the structure of that data, we're flying blind.

Comment: for `details`, I understood that to be a variable, so i made up the name (different from `card`). as far as what's being passed to the form, it's not showing up in the server output, i haven't purposefully redacted anything.  i'm assuming i should input `console.log(details);` some place?? where would i run this code. sorry for elementary questions

Comment: Yep - place console.log(details); right before the return ^ and see what it outputs.

Comment: like this?  `console.log(details);
          return Stripe.createToken(details, bank.handleStripeResponse);` it's giving me the same output. i also added before the final return in the js, same output.

Comment: Same as you've got for *FORM DATA:* in your q:?

Comment: yes, same as form data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46384/discussion-between-miler350-and-remus)

Comment: Was this ever answered? Having the same problem

Comment: It was not, sorry man.

Comment: Hey, FWIW. I ended up realizing it was a JS problem and not a Stripe problem. I ran a console log test and had nothing. So I just required the js files I needed in my app js require tree. It worked.